# How to nest EL inside EL?

Tags: jsf, el

I have Java enum type and I would like to get from `myEnum.name()` the associated i18n value.

I tested that :

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{rb.#{login.myEnum}}" />
```

(`rb` is my i18n variable defined in JSF faces-config.xml)

but it doesn't work.

I want EL expression that will be converted into `#{rb.KEY1}` and after `key1` or `clé1` or `schlüssel1` etc if the locale selected is English, French or German.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to try to use `#{}` inside `#{}` (and anyway its illegal...)

You should access it with the help of `[]` (like accessing a map)

Try it like this

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{rb[login.myEnum]}" />
```

Comment: very nice it works, didn't think of this code...Thank you !